# How to block quit and minimize activity? [Xamarin.Android]

Tags: android, user-interface, xamarin, navigation

I want to prevent from closing app by navigation buttons:
[image]

Can i do this in only one activity?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really the best you can do is prevent it from closing via the back button by override `OnBackPressed` in your activity:

```
    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        // do something to block closing app
    }
```

However, your other option is to essentially hide the navigation bar via overlay and permissions.
One thing to keep in mind with this is that some devices still have hardware navigation buttons (like Samsung devices) that can't be hidden.

If you're only targetting Android 5.0+ then you can use screen pinning. This feature is **NOT** recommended however, unless the application is something like an exam proctoring portal or something similar. Here's a great response that I couldn't do any better than: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/85125